# OS X move terminal caret with arrow keys

Tags: c++, c, terminal, command-line-interface

I made a simple C programme that demonstrates the issue. Here it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char buffer[128];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    printf("Type data:\n");
    scanf("%126s", buffer);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when the application is waiting for user input with scanf() and user user wants to edit line he typed, and to do move caret with arrows, the caret is not moving but new ugly input is inserted.
[image]

For some reason it does not handle the keys in a way I expect. I'm not able to go to the previous typed line with the up key, as well.

Obviously I should deliberately enable this behaviour. Could you advice, how can I do that?

Comment: You may have to use the ncurses library (or its equivalent on OS X) to be able to do the kind of Terminal-oriented I/O that you were talking about.  The standard C I/O functions deal with a stream of characters,  so they don't handle the escape characters sent by terminals well.

Comment: I thought about such a library, but shouldn't the terminal handle this itself? Many apps allow such manipulation and it seems strange that they all use non-standard libraries.

Comment: They all use non-standard libraries because there isn't a standard library to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`readline()`](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 80

int main() {
  char *line_buffer;
  int n, i;

  while (1) {
    line_buffer = readline("Say something: ");
    if (!line_buffer) break;
    for (i=0; line_buffer[i]; i++) {
      line_buffer[i] = toupper(line_buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("YOU SAID: %s\n",line_buffer);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}

/* (Compile with cc foo.c -lreadline -o foo) */
```